# Posting a JSon object to Webservice via AJAX

Tags: javascript, java, json, ajax, jersey

I'm trying to send an object in JSon format to my Java backend by AJAX, but I was unsuccessful.
I wonder if the syntax is properly correct.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.min.js.download"></script>
 <script src="scripts/jquery.imagemapster.js.download"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
 var myJSon = {"name":"Jo","age":30,"city":"Ny"};
     
       $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/Servidor/server',
  //contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  data: JSON.stringify(myJSon),
  success: function (data){
     alert('Sucess');
         },
  error: function () {
     alert('Error');
         }
       });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Send an HTTP POST request to a page and get the result back</button>

</body>
</html>
```

When the line `contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8"` is not commented out, I get the following error in the backend: `INFO: Could not find grammar element for class java.lang.String`

Is the syntax correct? Can the error be from the backend itself?

P.S.: Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Voting to close due typo.

Comment: what means duo typo?

Comment: In this site you'll see the «typo» when the issue that you have is due a **typographical error** in your code. In this case, you had «sucess» instead «success».

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767973/jersey-what-does-couldnt-find-grammar-element-mean.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good, you just misspelled "success" on the AJAX call (you need 2 letter c's instead of 1). So replace `sucess: function(data){...}` with `success: function(data){...}` https://jsfiddle.net/stephentillman/aow5pah2/

Comment: thanks, i edited in the publication, because the error remains, I saw that in your link is working, would it then be a back-end problem?